# Child window loses focus after MessageBox is displayed

Tags: c++, winapi

So i have created a main window inside of which i have created a 2 child windows. They all have different **WindowProcs**. At the `WM_CREATE` message of the main window I am giving focus to one of the child windows with `SetFocus(...)`. After I display a `MessageBox` from the child window proc the focus is set back to main window. How can I maintain focus on the child window?

Comment: Call SetFocus after MessageBox

Comment: @rkosegi Thanks it works, although it's a hack, but it's an working hack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the message box window is [destroyed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms632599.aspx#destruction), Windows makes another *top-level* window the [active window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms632599.aspx#active).  If that’s not what you want, it is up to you to respond to the [`WM_SETFOCUS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms646283.aspx) message that your main (top-level) window will receive and use [`SetFocus()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms646312.aspx) to direct the focus to the child.